# WooCommerce form field select in cart that lists custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom post type **good_cause**. I can pull the custom post type's title and populate a drop down on the cart.

What I'm **trying to accomplish** is for the post's titles to be the **options in the woocommerce_form_field** instead of the **static value**.

```php
<?php

add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'wps_add_select_checkout_field');
function wps_add_select_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

echo '<h2>'.__('Select a Good Cause').'</h2>';




$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'good_cause',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<select>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            echo '<option value="' . get_the_ID() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</option>';


    endwhile;
    echo '</select>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
 endif;



    woocommerce_form_field( 'daypart', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'wps-drop' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Delivery options' ),


        'options'       => array(
            'blank'     => __( 'Select a day part', 'wps' ),
            'morning'   => __( 'In the morning', 'wps' ),
            'afternoon' => __( 'In the afternoon', 'wps' ),
            'evening'   => __( 'In the evening', 'wps' )
        )
 ),

    $checkout->get_value( 'daypart' ));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing these (echo) you can add the values ​​to an `$options` array, then use this array as `woocommerce_form_field( 'options' );`

```php
function wps_add_select_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    echo '<h2>'.__('Select a Good Cause').'</h2>';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'good_cause',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Set variable (array)
    $options = array();

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            // Add to $options array
            $options[get_the_ID()] = get_the_title();
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
     endif;

    woocommerce_form_field( 'daypart', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'wps-drop' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Delivery options' ),
        'options'       => $options
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'daypart' ));

}
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'wps_add_select_checkout_field', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: That worked perfected... just the concept I wasn't grasping.  Thank You